# Detect if .on() is updating or fetching initial data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When my app boots up it fetches a bunch of jobs using

```
ref.on('value', snapshot => {
  // DO STUFF WITH snapshot.val()
});
```

I know the `.on()`listener will fire every time the node changes.

For my app I manage the app state differently depending if the app is booting up OR if it already booted up and the `.on()` listener is firing because the node UPDATED.

As per the docs:

> The listener is triggered once for the initial state of the data and again anytime the data changes.

Is there any way to know, if the `.on()` is firing because a change to the node has been made or it is the first load?

Thanks!